# D3 multi line data point circle getting out of line

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, d3.js

I've been trying to build a multiline chart of three lines and display tooltip along with circles on data points when hovered over. However the circle is not following the line and at certain data points and it comes out of the line. Setting the element focus, for the particular line by adjusting transform, translate for the specific line solves the issue but then messes up the other lines. How to pass all the datasets instead of one dataset on `focus` element? I tried sorting all the datasets in one common dataset consisting of all the objects and pass it on transform of `focus` but that is also making the circle shift away from the lines at certain datapoints

```
  drawAUCROCGraphExpanded(fprTpr_train, fprTpr_test, fprTpr_oot, fprTpr_default, trainroc, testroc, ootroc) {
var margin = { top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 0 },
  width = 560 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 395 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// Draw the X-axis on the DOM
this.aucRocSvgExpanded.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));

// Draw the Y-axis on the DOM
this.aucRocSvgExpanded.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10));

var valueline = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
  .x(function (d: any) { return x(d.fpr); })
  .y(function (d: any) { return y(d.tpr); });

var valueline2 = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
  .x(function (d: any) { return x(d.fpr); })
  .y(function (d: any) { return y(d.tpr); });

var valueline3 = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
  .x(function (d: any) { return x(d.fpr); })
  .y(function (d: any) { return y(d.tpr); });

var valueline4 = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
  .x(function (d: any) { return x(d.fpr); })
  .y(function (d: any) { return y(d.tpr); });

x.domain([0, 1]);
y.domain([0, 1]);

this.aucRocSvgExpanded.append("path")
  .attr("style", 'stroke: #c1c2c2; stroke-width: 2; fill: none; stroke-dasharray: 3, 4.5;')
  .attr("d", valueline(fprTpr_default))


this.aucRocSvgExpanded.append("path")
  .attr("style", 'stroke: #2E4A71; stroke-width: 2; fill: none;')
  //.style('fill', d => fprTpr_flag == true ? '#e6e8ed;' : null )
  .attr("d", valueline2(fprTpr_train))
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

if (fprTpr_test.length > 0) {
  this.aucRocSvgExpanded.append("path")
    .attr("style", 'stroke: #517BAD; stroke-width: 2; fill: none;')
    //.style('fill', d => fprTpr_flag == true ? '#e6e8ed;' : null )
    .attr("d", valueline3(fprTpr_test))
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
}

if (fprTpr_oot.length > 0) {
  this.aucRocSvgExpanded.append("path")
    .attr("style", 'stroke: #74A0D8; stroke-width: 2; fill: none;')
    .attr("d", valueline4(fprTpr_oot))
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
}

var focus = this.aucRocSvgExpanded.append("g")
  .attr("class", "focus")
  .style("display", "none")

// append the x line
focus.append("line")
  .attr("class", "x")
  .style("stroke", "blue")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "3,3")
  .style("opacity", 0.5)
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", height);


// append the circles at the intersection
focus.append("circle")
  .attr("id", "train_circle")
  .style("fill", "#2E4A71")
  .style("stroke", "#2E4A71")
  .attr("r", 4);

if (fprTpr_test.length > 0) {
  focus.append("circle")
    .attr("id", "test_circle")
    .style("fill", "#517BAD")
    .style("stroke", "#517BAD")
    .attr("r", 4);
}

if (fprTpr_oot.length > 0) {
  focus.append("circle")
    .attr("id", "oot_circle")
    .style("fill", "#74A0D8")
    .style("stroke", "#74A0D8")
    .attr("r", 4);
}


var bisectData = d3.bisector((d: any) => d.fpr).right,
  sortData_train = fprTpr_train.sort(function (a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.fpr, b.fpr) }),
  sortData_test = fprTpr_test.sort(function (a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.fpr, b.fpr) }),
  sortData_oot = fprTpr_oot.sort(function (a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.fpr, b.fpr) })

const mouseover = () => {
  focus.style("display", null);
  this.roc_tooltipExpanded.style("display", "block")
}

const mouseout = () => {
  focus.style("display", "none");
  this.roc_tooltipExpanded.style("display", "none")
}

const mousemove = (event) => {
  var x0 = x.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]),
      i = bisectData(sortData_train, x0, 1),
      j = bisectData(sortData_test, x0, 1),
      k = bisectData(sortData_oot, x0, 1),
      a = sortData_train[i].fpr,
      d = sortData_train[i].tpr

  if (fprTpr_test.length > 0) {
    var b = sortData_test[j].fpr,
        e = sortData_test[j].tpr
  }

  if (fprTpr_oot.length > 0) {
    var c = sortData_oot[k].fpr,
        f = sortData_oot[k].tpr
  }

  if (fprTpr_oot.length > 0) {
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(sortData_oot[k].fpr) + "," + 0 + ")");
  } else if (fprTpr_test.length > 0) {
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(sortData_test[j].fpr) + "," + 0 + ")");     //selecting one of this fixes issue for the particular line but messes up others
  } else {
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(sortData_train[i].fpr) + "," + 0 + ")");
  }

  var roc_label;

  if (fprTpr_oot.length > 0 && fprTpr_test.length > 0) {
    roc_label = `<div style="height: 20px; padding: 2px 4px; background-color: #E6E8ED;"">AUC:</div><div style="background-color: #fff; padding: 2px 4px"><div style = "color: #2E4A71;"><span>Train:</span> ${trainroc} - <b>${d}</b></div><div style="color: #517BAD;"><span style="padding: 0px 7px 0px 0px;">Test:</span> ${testroc} - <b>${e}</b></div><div style="color: #74A0D8;"><span style="padding: 0px 6px 0px 0px;">OOT:</span> ${ootroc} - <b>${f}</b></div></div>`;
  } else if (fprTpr_test.length > 0 && fprTpr_oot.length <= 0) {
    roc_label = `<div style="height: 20px; padding: 2px 4px; background-color: #E6E8ED;"">AUC:</div><div style="background-color: #fff; padding: 2px 4px"><div style = "color: #2E4A71;><span>Train:</span> ${trainroc} - <b>${d}</b></div><div style="color: #517BAD;><span style="padding: 0px 7px 0px 0px;">Test:</span> ${testroc} - <b>${e}</b></div></div>`;
  } else if (fprTpr_test.length <= 0 && fprTpr_oot.length > 0) {
    roc_label = `<div style="height: 20px; padding: 2px 4px; background-color: #E6E8ED;"">AUC:</div><div style="background-color: #fff; padding: 2px 4px"><div style = "color: #2E4A71;><span>Train:</span> ${trainroc} - <b>${d}</b></div><div style="color: #74A0D8;"><span style="padding: 0px 6px 0px 0px;">OOT:</span> ${ootroc} - <b>${f}</b></div></div>`;
  } else {
    roc_label = `<div style="height: 20px; padding: 2px 4px; background-color: #E6E8ED;"">AUC:</div><div style="background-color: #fff; padding: 2px 4px"><div style = "color: #2E4A71;><span>Train:</span> ${trainroc} - <b>${d}</b></div></div>`;
  }

  this.roc_tooltipExpanded
    .html(roc_label)
    // .style("left", (d3.pointer(event)[0]+40) + "px")
    .style("right", (d3.pointer(event)[0]) + "px")
    .style("top", (d3.pointer(event)[1]) + "px")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .style("z-index", "1")
    .style("display", "block")
    focus.select("circle#train_circle").attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + "," + y(sortData_train[i].tpr) + ")")
  if (fprTpr_test.length > 0) {
    focus.select("circle#test_circle").attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + "," + y(sortData_test[j].tpr) + ")")
  }
  if (fprTpr_oot.length > 0) {
    focus.select("circle#oot_circle").attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + "," + y(sortData_oot[k].tpr) + ")")
  }
}

this.aucRocSvgExpanded.append("g")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("fill", "transparent")
  .on("mouseover", mouseover)
  .on("mouseout", mouseout)
  .on("mousemove", mousemove);

this.aucRocSvgExpanded.append("g")
  .append("text")
  .attr('y', 390)
  .attr('x', 280)
  .style("font-size", "14px")
  .style("font-weight", "600")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("FPR");

this.aucRocSvgExpanded.append("g")
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr('y', -35)
  .attr('x', -180)
  .style("font-size", "14px")
  .style("font-weight", "600")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("TPR");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check if it works after you remove `.curve`. That happens because the curve changes the actual points to smooth out the line.

Comment: You don't have a reproducible example here, but I don't believe the `curve` is your issue.  One problem is your seem to be moving your `focus` `g` based only one dataset, while moving each `circle` independently.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers that's the issue. How do you suggest to move ```focus``` by all the dataset?